# How to detect is audio or video is being played in linux using python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, audio, video

I want to check if the user is actively using the Linux computer  or not for that I have to detect if the audio or video is being played in the computer or not.

How to do that detect that using Python?

If you have information how to do it in windows also let me know.

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer you can use dbus library of python to detact that.

Here below is the code for that

```
import dbus

def is_media_playing():
    bus = dbus.SessionBus()
    for service in bus.list_names():
        if service.startswith('org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.'):
            player = dbus.SessionBus().get_object(service, '/org/mpris/MediaPlayer2')
            status = player.Get('org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.Player', 'PlaybackStatus', dbus_interface='org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties')
            if status == 'Playing':
                return True
    return False

if is_media_playing():
    print("Media is playing")
else:
    print("Media is not playing")
```

if you want the complete details for the media file being played you can use the below code

```
# !/usr/bin/env python3
import dbus
bus = dbus.SessionBus()
for service in bus.list_names():
    if service.startswith('org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.'):
        player = dbus.SessionBus().get_object(service, '/org/mpris/MediaPlayer2')

        status=player.Get('org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.Player', 'PlaybackStatus', dbus_interface='org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties')
        print(status)

        metadata = player.Get('org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.Player', 'Metadata', dbus_interface='org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties')
        print(metadata)
```